# openldap olcAccess Rule Request

Tags: security, permissions, openldap

### I need to applying some limitation for my DN via **olcAccess**
For example;

- 1.1: users can change their **own passwords**,
- 1.2: `cn=administrators,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com` group can also modify all user attributes under "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" organizational unit

---

- 2: for specific user; "uid: devsuper,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", can modify all **user attributes**, users are in member of  `cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com` group, except "removing user from DN (it means can delete attrs but not entry)"

---

- 3: How can I reject external requests to my ldap server?; for example, any user can call URL QUERY `curl 'ldap://ldap.example.com/dc=example,dc=com??sub?'`, can I prevent request like this? or can I returning a "custom message"?

---

I hope the rulesets are written

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.